# How do I make certain files accessible just for PHP scripts?

Tags: php, session, .htaccess, cookies

I'm building a CMS and the main page (`index.php`) is being built up from a lot of small files in the CMS's directory. For example, the structure could be like this:

```
index.php
menu/admin/content.php
           config.php
           requests.php

menu/tools/content.php
           config.php
           requests.php

menu/users/content.php
           config.php
           requests.php
```

When I access the `index.php` in the root directory, I get a different result based on the `$_GET` parameters. For example, when I access `index.php?section=tools`, the index file loads up the `content`, `cofnig` and `requests` files from `menu/tools/` folder.

Now to the problem. The `index.php` page itself is accessible just for the logged in users, but for security reasons, I'd like to disable everything in `menu` folder from being accessed by any other way, than by php's include function.

To demonstrate what could happen: If I want to delete something, I use `index.php?section=tools&delete=5`, and in the `menu/tools/requests.php` file, I would check if `$_GET['delete']` is set and then delete ID of 5 from the DB. Now the problem is that, if someone knew the actual structure, (s)he could access the `requests.php` file like this: `site.com/admin/menu/tools/requests.php?delete=5`, and hack the site that way.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of possible attacks? Something to deny access for the files in menu folder, but still let them be accessed from my index.php file? Htaccess maybe? I really don't feel like putting a check (if session/cookie is set) to every single file in the 'menu' folder, although that would be a possible solution.

Comment: index.php?section=tools&delete=5 is a bad idea in and of itself. I couldn't find the reference right now, but there was a case I read about where an entire website was destroyed by a benevolent bot because each item had a "delete" link. Use POST requests instead.

Answer (score 3):

Create a .htaccess in the folder(s) you wan't to deny access to containing the following:

```
deny from all
```

The best would be to have the folder outside of the web root, though.

Comment: Well, is there a way to put the files outside of the root when using normal hosting services?

Comment: There should be, although some (bad) shared hosts only let you access the web root.

Comment: Well, I tryed the "Deny from all" and it works fine. Just a thing I'm not sure about, is there a way for someone outsite to access the file, if there is the .htaccess rule? For example if he was to use CURL, or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to move the `menu` folder to somewhere outside the document root of the webserver. That way, no URL maps to `menu/tools/requests.php` and your only safety concern is what you do in `index.php`

Comment: Well, or I could rename the 'menu' folder to a 'menu145235234952' or something like this and change the number for every project, but that doesn't seem like a clean solution. I don't really know where I would move it, I always use hosting services.

Comment: It should be possible. For the details, ask your hosting service provider.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah check with your provider, you should have access to at least your account's `$HOME` which typically contains the folder where your webroot(s) are stored. If they dont give this kind of access its probably a good sign you should switch providers :-)

Comment: Well, wouln't "DENY FROM ALL" in .htaccess have the same efect, as puting it in a folder, that can't be accessed?

Comment: That depends on the configuration of the webserver. Considering that you are using a hosting service and that you therefor do not have any influence on the configuration of the webserver, I wouldn't rely on the configuration of the webserver for security-critical stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if someone were to manually add the GET arguments and "hack" the site there is a problem. In the script, you should be verifying the authentication of the user trying to perform these actions, and if they are authenticated then there should be no problem. I don't think anyone is going to cause problems deleting something via GET param, when they can do it on the interface themselves.

There are solutions the way you asked, but they each have their own concerns...

CodeIgniter works by setting a variable, and then on the head of each script,

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

You could also check $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to see if its index.php, else exit.