# Make file only accessible for php

Tags: php, apache2, privileges, access-control

I want to make files in a specific directory only accessible for php, concrete situation is, that I have a folder with some subfolders in it, and each subfolder contains a lot of files (can be every type of file, like images, code, executable files, etc.). Now I built a script to be able to download the files, which works, BUT theres also the possibility to just go to `server.com/folder/subfolder/img.jpg` to view the image. That is what I don't want to allow.

Is there any way I can do this?

PS: I'm running a Ubuntu 14.04 server with apache2 and PHP7.

**Edit**: Question might be duplicate to the question linked, but no answer works for me, .htaccess doesn't change anything and the folder should stay where it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make certain files accessible just for PHP scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757510/how-do-i-make-certain-files-accessible-just-for-php-scripts)

Comment: You try the wrong approach. Something like that is _not_ solved by file system internal permission handling, that is impossible. Instead you use a "router script" that handles requests to any such files, whilst the files themselves are not reachable by means of a direct http request _at all_. They are stored outside the published file tree portion. The routing script can use whtever strategy you want to authorize a request and then "hand out" a file by first sending apropriate http headers and then the files content itself.

Comment: @arkascha why doesn't a .htaccess file with "deny from all" work then?

Comment: Sure that can be done, though you'd have to implement exceptions for certain files again. But I would not count that as a secure or elegant solution. It spreads your applications logic over different levels in your setup and requires all components to work together perfectly. If not, you have a security or data breach. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow the http server down. Whereas in a routing script you can use all the flexibility a scripting language gives into your hands. Logging, modifying, one-some-many approaches, ...

Comment: @arkascha so you think I could move the folder with the subfolders and files in it in another folder not accessible from browser anyway (so in `/var` instead of `/var/www`?

Comment: That actually is the standard approach, since it is secure by definition (kind of opt-in instead of opt-out under your own control) and cleans up your application setup: you always want to store logic and data/payload (files here) in different locations.

Comment: @arkascha and how do I know allow php to go to that subfolder? Just created it in `/var` and then in php just tried to write a `../` in front of every path working with that folder but that doesn't work..

Comment: Two things: first you should use an absolute path to access the location where your data is stored (so something like `/var/data`) and that path should come from some static configuration file in your setup. Second you _may_ have to grant php to access that location. For that you need to know what blocks the access if anything at all. For that take a look into your http servers error log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to address this using the filesystem you have to recognize that you have some significant limitations system-wise.  Your PHP scripts for example cannot run as the same user as Apache, and therefore cannot run in Apache.

If this is a hard requirement the first thing I would do is to run the PHP scripts via a fcgi daemon rather than the web server, have that run as a separate user, and tighten file permissions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourwebsite/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /yourwebsite/404.php
```

put this in your .htaccess and when someone goes to your website they will see only what is in the public folder but everything outside the public folder will still be accessible by php only images and css must be inside the public folder because otherwise the user cant see it because he has no permissions